# Plugin issue in Android Studio after computer crashed

Tags: android-studio

When I run my app in Android Studio the screen of my mac freezed, so I shutted it down. When I reopened Android Studio that's what appears:
[image: error]

What do I have to do now?

Comment: I'd probably completely reinstall android studio. That error sounds particularly heavy duty, and definitely not something there is a 'correct' fix for.

Comment: Found it out eventually. I only had yo click "enable android support" and it automatically reinstalled all the plugins

Comment: Well that was an easy fix to a dangerous looking error message ;)

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved: just click "enable Android Support" and it will automatically reinstall all the plugins